# what are the differences between Vundle and NeoBundle?

Tags: vim

I would like to have a nice and easy way of managing vim plugins.
I found [NeoBundle](https://github.com/Shougo/neobundle.vim) and [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).
What are the main differences between them? I know that NeoBundle is a fork of Vundle, but what is it that makes it different?

What do you use?

Comment: Neither of them. I use pathogen and until now quite happy with it :)

Comment: Not sure why this has two downvotes.  It's a reasonable question.  The non-answer-but-best-solution is still pathogen, though. :)

Comment: really? i read everywhere that vundle and neo are better, because they handle updating without submodules. what is your way of updating?

Comment: Vundle/NeoBundle for the win! Vundle is essentially a big improvement on pathogen.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

[Here](http://vim-jp.org/vim-users-jp/2011/10/25/Hack-238.html) is an article written (in Japanese) by the author of `NeoBundle` Shougo, about why he wrote `NeoBundle` and how `NeoBundle` differs from `Vundle`.

Actually, `NeoBundle` is a fork of `Vundle`. Shougo added some features to a fork of `Vundle` but lately found he couldn't follow the upstream `Vundle`'s development, so he made the fork to a new plugin now called `NeoBundle`.

The differences summarized as below:

1. Rename the commands from `Vundle`, replace `Bundle` to `NeoBundle`. (Example: `BundelInstall` to `NeoBundleInstall`).
2. Add support for [vital.vim](https://github.com/vim-jp/vital.vim), a vim utility library written by [thinca](https://github.com/thinca).
3. `Neobundle` works even you have set the `shellslash` option other than the default.
4. Add support for [vimproc](https://github.com/Shougo/vimproc), a launcher plugin written by Shougo.
5. Add an interface for [unite.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/unite.vim) written by Shougo, he also notes it as the major motive for writing `NeoBundle`.
6. Add support for plugins that hosted as a Subversion/Mercurial repository, but it is still an experimental feature now.
7. (**UPDATED**) Now `NeoBundle` adds a lazy loading feature where `Vundle` doesn't have. It allows you to load plugins at some user-defined time point, not only during the vim initialization where `.vimrc` is loaded.

I use `vundle` because it suffices my needs (I used pathogen before). But you can take a try at `NeoBundle`.

---

(**UPDATE**) `NeoBundle` has stopped active development now and will be replaced by [dein.vim](https://github.com/Shougo/dein.vim), which is Shougo's another brand new plugin manager. As a side note, you can also take a look at [vim-plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) which I'm currently using.

Comment: I think you should mention that the article explaining NeoBundle author's motivations is written in Japanese.

Comment: Its seems dein by the same author is now the better plugin manager so even I switched to it recently.